# While loop is breaking because of no id found

Tags: javascript, c#, repeater

So I have a page with nested repeaters on it. The nested repeater is throwing off my Container.ItemIndex so in my Javascript function when I look for the certain IDs it breaks once it gets to the nested numbers. Parent repeater goes 0-9 but then it has the nested one use 10-19. My main repeater starts up again at 20 but the javascript breaks as soon as it hits 10. I need to have the funciton run 0-9 AND 20-32. Is there any way to turn off the itemindex on the nested repeater or look for all my numbers in the javascript?

Javascript Function

```
while(document.getElementByID("pricePerUnit_"+orderId+i)
{
i++
}
```

Aspx page

```
<tr id="mainTr<%# Container.ItemIndex %>">
```

Main repeater that uses 0-9 then 20-32

Comment: Are you just looking for a count of elements with ID that starts with pricePerUnit_?

Comment: I need to get into the loop for that, it would be pricePerUnit_46899(then the I) but that is whats throwing it off, i tried to look at starts with but wasnt sure how to do it in a while loop

Comment: Sorry think I wasnt clear, the id is what holds the name, its a TR with that as the id. <tr id="pricePerUnit_46899(Container.ItemIndex)" on it.

Comment: Sorry guys i just saw where it was by tagname not id, like my last message i have tried a couple of different ways.

Comment: If you can use jQuery you can use the starts with selector and then just select by "pricePerUnit_". Once you have all the elements, you can iterate through them using a for loop.